# how to find the creation block_number for a given contract_address using web3.py?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, solidity, web3py

I was trying to find the creation block number using contract address , is there is a way to find creation block number when a contract address is deployed using web3.py?

Answer (score -1):

well, there are 2 things you can do with ** web3.py ** and one thing you can do with **etherscan** ***(or any other explorer from the etherscan group)***

**1) web3:**

You will need not only the address but also the hash of the creation transaction, so you can do  `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(*hash*)` The resulting object will contain a blockNumber.

**2) web3:**

This will take a lot of **time** and **effort**, but you can **create a script** that will check every transaction from **block 0** *(or a block that you are sure is before your contract creation block)* and check all the data within each transaction to find the correct block

**3) etherscan:**

you can call **etherscan API** - see "get transaction list" at etherscan.io/apis#accounts

Comment: okay thankyou, but we need to check the creation block number with the help of just contract address , will it work for that?

Comment: @KavitaJoshi yeah, you can use method 2 or 3